# diffrence between submitted page and indexed in googlemap

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search-console

i want to optimize rank of my site in search engines especially Google . i have submitted a sitemap to Google ; after about a week i see that 170 page had been  submitted  but just one page has been indexed. is there something wrong with it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't certain that there is something wrong.

Google first reads your sitemap. It is reporting that it found 170 urls in your sitemap, and has queued them up to be considered.

A week later it has decided to add one page to its index. One of two things has happened: google has not gotten around to crawling ( that is reading ) and considering all the pages in your sitemap. Or Google has looked at your pages and decided not to add them to its index.

Look in webmaster tools under "google index", "index status", "advanced". Then select "ever crawled". It should show you how many URLs it crawled from your site. If they haven't been crawled yet, you may just have to wait.

If they have been crawled, and are not added to the index, consider improving your content - or try the "fetch as googlebot" feature to make sure that what you are sending to google is what you think. Sometimes things can be configured so they look good to users, but are not visible to googlebot - e.g. all your content is ajaxed or in flash or something.

Also make sure that you aren't disallowing google to crawl your site in robots.txt, and that you are allowing the pages to be indexed. ( check to make sure you do not have a "noindex" tag in your html ).

Comment: tanx i got my answer ; but i try site:www.vilashahr.org i see (About 63 results (0.16 seconds) ) are these 63 page indexed ?if so why i just have one indexed pag

Comment: The pages that google actually indexed may be different from the ones in your sitemap. So Google may have rejected the pages in the sitemap, but then found pages on the site that it like. You could also have problems with canonicals or redirects.